# DateTime.Now into SQL datetime column

Tags: c#, sql, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql

I have c# code populating my database via linq,

```
 Post post = new Post();

 post.Creator = AccountHelpers.CurrentUser.UserID;
 post.Message = message;
 post.TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;               


 context.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(post); 
 context.SubmitChanges();
```

When this is ran however, the database is showing the correct date, without any time created making it impossible to filter by age.

For example, an item made today at 20:25 is showing in the SQL database as 2014-08-10 00:00:00.000 - I would like the time to be shown in there also.

My table is the following

```
[MessageID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Creator] [int] NOT NULL,
[TimeCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter by age"? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: What the type of column in database (datetime or date)?

Comment: Its a datetime.

And filter by age - later in my code I am ordering by date desc, then producing the top 10 results. if no time is given then more than 10 posts per day will ruin this

Comment: What do you expect to get from this insert? What do you mean by TimeStamp - TimeCreated column or SQL timestamp? What is "the database is showing the correct date, without any time stamps"? If it is difficult to describe issues verbally, then show the rows from the database (one row as you want it to be, another as it ends after submit).

Comment: Show the schema of your table (datatypes of its columns) and corresponding entities(mappings).

Comment: @LiamHT Can you add your entities(mappings)?

Comment: theres nothing wrong with the mappings or entities. I'm thinking that its just having a hard time converting from MM DD YYYY to YYYY MM DD

Comment: try to re-run at a different time. perhaps you saved it at 0:00 seconds on that date. if not that! :) then it has got to be the entity mappings, ensure the data type is not set to Date rather than DateTime. Or even double check the property to ensure that there isnt any rouge attributes.

Comment: Ive tried a few, I tried datetime.now.AddDays(21) and it still showed no time ... i guess ill have to keep trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix came from the DBML being edited in source control and not telling me, entity mappings changed..

How embarrassing!

Comment: Just delete the question then.

Comment: Also: be careful about `DateTime.Now`: http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/

Comment: @MattJohnson: There was a question today which exhibited the exact same behavior. Also EF and a DateTime field (can't find it now). Maybe it can stay, it's an eye opener for whomever runs into it.